# What is the physical significance of velocity weighted cross section?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, scattering, probability, scattering-cross-section

Consider two types of bodies. Their encounter cross section is given by $\sigma$, where $\sigma\equiv\sigma(u)$ and $u$ is the relative velocity of the encounter. I gather that "cross section" is a synonym for probability.

The velocity weighted cross section is $<\sigma u> = \int\mathrm{d}^3uf_u(u)u\sigma(u)$. Here, $f_u(u)$ is the distribution of the encounter velocity. What is the physical significance of the velocity weighted cross section?

Comment: What I would recommend you to do is to just do a dimensional analysis of $\sigma u$. It basically gives you the rate constant of a collision, i.e., number of collisions (you have the cross section data for) per unit time per unit density. The weighting accounts for the number of particles available for collisions at a certain relative velocity $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Cross section is not quite a synonym for probability. It has the dimensions of length squared and can be validly thought of as the area of a notional target (even though the details do not bear close examination). To get the probability you have to divide by the area of the target, so if a particle traverses a thin object of area $A$, thickness $x$, containing $n$ (other) particles per unit volume each with cross section $\sigma$, the probability that it will interact is $n A x \sigma /A=n\sigma x$.

That's appropriate if you're interested in the rate of interactions per thickness.  If you're interested in the rate of interactions per time then you just have to include the fact that fast particles traver further: $x=vt$. So the probability of interacting in time $t$ is $n \sigma v t$ .  If you integrate over a range of velocities you need to integrate $\sigma v$ not just $\sigma$.